# How to convert xml elements into string

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

Below is my code: I am getting response in XML in putContactResponse and I want to convert its node into string

```
if (putContactResponse != string.Empty)
    {
        var responseElement = XElement.Parse(putContactResponse);
        string statusCode = responseElement.XPathSelectElement("/Status").Value;
}
```

Comment: ...Can you say what the issue is? Why is that not working? Exception perhaps? Won't compile.. ? What's the compiler error?

Answer (score 1):

This will get the content of the element if the content is text:

```
responseElement.Value
```

This will get the content of the element as XML:

```
responseElement.InnerXML
```

This will get the element and its content as XML

```
responseElement.OuterXML
```

Comment: inner xml/outer xml is not working with .value i am getting its value as i want its node also

Comment: not working means ? what do you get when you try them ...get error or some response ? and it would be better if you provide your xml schema

Answer (score 0):

XElement has a properties FirstNode and NextNode, you can use this on responseElement to get the Nodes.

Else you can use the XElement.Name and XElement.Value properties to fetch the values after XPathSelectElement